# AVPlayer not playing HD Videos of Large Dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a Kiosk app that receives videos from the Dropbox SDK, saves the Data into the Temp Directory and plays it back on a loop using AVPlayerLayer.

I have absolutely no issues when playing videos that are small/medium (1334x750), but larger dimensions (3888x2592) do not appear at all. Can somebody direct me to a possible solution or way of debugging what might be going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
func playVideo(data: Data) {
    playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    let path = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    let url = path.appendingPathComponent("temp.mov")

    do {
        try data.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
    } catch let error {
        print("WRITING: \(error)")
    }

    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
    videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.loopVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

}

func loopVideo() {

        player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        player.play()

}
```

Comment: Same issue, if you find something please share!

Comment: So far I only found out that there is an exact cutoff in dimensions after which AVPlayer doesnt play. It has nothing to do with the quality or size of the file.